# Query replacing ("Did you mean") with my own one-way dictionary in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have a TXT file (that I created based on some statistical analysis) that contains mapping from a mistyped query to a correct query. Example:

```
citroen xsara pikasso -> citroen xsara picasso
jamaha -> yamaha
leahter trousers -> leather trousers
a stationery vehicle -> a stationary vehicle
a stationary spplier -> a stationery supplier
a stationary suplier -> a stationery supplier
```

I am looking for a way to do something like this: if user enters a query that is on the left-hand side of this file, SOLR should **suggest** replacing it with a query on the right-hand side.

I read about FileBasedSpellChecker (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FileBasedSpellChecker) but it only allows a dictionary of words, not mappings. I also read about SynonymFilterFactory and it takes a map file (https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/2.4/Collections/Synonyms-Files.html) but it just makes SOLR search for the phrases on the right-hand side of the map file - it does not provide suggestions. So none of the plugins work for my case.

Is there a plugin that does something like this: if query == "A" then suggest "B"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [SuggesterComponent](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester)? specifically, you could check the `FileDictionaryFactory`?

From your examples, sounds like you don't want "suggestions" persè this sounds more like query rewriting. But if we take your previous example and only highlight the differences in your queries:

```
citroen xsara **pikasso** -> citroen xsara **picasso**
**jamaha** -> **yamaha**
leahter trousers -> leather trousers
a **stationery** vehicle -> a **stationary** vehicle
a stationary **spplier** -> a stationery **supplier**
a stationary **suplier** -> a stationery **supplier**
```

You see that basically, you're suggesting the same query and only changing some misspelled words/terms, this could be implemented using the Suggester/Spellchecker and only adding the "right spelled term" that you're finding in the external statistical process, instead of the full query.